MUI select box remains in the exact same position in terms of viewport height and viewport width when scrolling
When I click on the MUI select the select box (dropdown) remains in the exact same position in terms of viewport height and viewport width when scrolling, when it should always be positioned just below the select. How do I solve this?
Tried to change the positioning of the FormControl och Select

I think you cannot scroll while the select (dropdown) is open. Can you please share a code sandbox?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

MUI Selectbox when opened opens in presentation mode(which is a modal) and the dropdown list also opens in presentation mode or presentation layer in which case page scroll is not available. In order to vertically scroll the page, first the dropdown list will need to be closed by clicking anywhere on screen.
Please clarify whether this is the case you're talking about.
